# Непонятный отступ между блоками в Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Пытаюсь создать хедер, что состоит из нескольких слоев. И между первым и вторым появился этот отступ (скриншот). Что я сделал не так? Каких-то маржинов и падингов там нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:
Даже если добавить надписи на фоне свойство display: none, ее отсутствие почти не влияет на этот отступ и он остается в любом случае (скриншот 2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
    transition: .5s;
    outline: none;
}

body { 
    background-color: #282828;
}

header .row,
header {
    min-height: 85vh;
    background-color: #191919;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.logo .name {
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 100%;
    user-select: none;   

    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;

}

.headings {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.headings .item {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 10px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.headings .active {
    opacity: 1;
    color: #DB2700;
}

.item:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.type {
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.bgString {
    user-select: none;   
    margin-top: -45px;
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 230px;
    line-height: 100%;

    font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;

    color: #282828;

    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.bgString .dark {
    color: #191919;
}

.mainHeader {
    width: 464px;
    height: 155px;
}

h1{
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 100%;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
}

.mainHeader button {

    background: #DB2700;
    border-radius: 75px;
    border: none;    
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;

    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.mainHeader button:hover {
    background: #ff2f00;
}

.social .item {

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#070d0f">
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <title>Savelev</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-start">
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 logo">
                    <img src="/images/header/logoIone 3.svg" alt="Logo">
                    <span class="name">SAVELEV</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 headings">
                    <div class="item sneakers active">
                        <img src="/images/header/Sneakers.svg" alt="Sneakers">
                        <span class="type">Sneakers</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item cloathes">
                        <img src="/images/header/Cloathes.svg" alt="Cloathes">
                        <span class="type">Cloathes</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item accessories">
                        <img src="/images/header/Accessories.svg" alt="Accessories">
                        <span class="type">Accessories</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item other">
                        <img src="/images/header/Other.svg" alt="Other">
                        <span class="type">Other</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="bgString">OCTOPU<span class="dark">S</span></div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="mainHeader">
                        <h1>VISUALIZE YOUR ITEM</h1>
                        <button type="button" class="contactBtn">Contact me</button>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-5"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>

                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="social">
                        <img class="item" src="/images/header/social_behance.svg" alt="Behance">
                        <img class="item" src="/images/header/social_instagram.svg" alt="Instagram">
                        <img class="item" src="/images/header/social_youtube.svg" alt="YouTube">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>



    <!--

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из-за повернутой надписи, которая в `.bgString`, как раз где-то 230px(высота шрифта font-size). Обнулите высоту: `height: 0` . Кроме того - нужно убрать `.header .row {height: 85vh}` - из-за этого горизонтальные блоки распределяются по высоте, порождая отступы(особенность flex). Визуально высота этого блока роли не играет.

```css
* {
    transition: .5s;
    outline: none;
}

body { 
    background-color: #282828;
}

header {
    min-height: 85vh;
    background-color: #191919;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.logo .name {
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 100%;
    user-select: none;   

    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;

}

.headings {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.headings .item {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 10px;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.headings .active {
    opacity: 1;
    color: #DB2700;
}

.item:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.type {
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
    margin-top: 7px;
}

.bgString {
    user-select: none;   
    margin-top: -45px;
    font-family: Oswald;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 230px;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
    height: 0;
    color: #282828;

    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.bgString .dark {
    color: #191919;
}

.mainHeader {
    width: 464px;
    height: 155px;
}

h1{
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 100%;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
}

.mainHeader button {

    background: #DB2700;
    border-radius: 75px;
    border: none;    
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;

    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.mainHeader button:hover {
    background: #ff2f00;
}

.social .item {

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#070d0f">
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <title>Savelev</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-start">
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 logo">
                    <img src="/images/header/logoIone 3.svg" alt="Logo">
                    <span class="name">SAVELEV</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 headings">
                    <div class="item sneakers active">
                        <img src="/images/header/Sneakers.svg" alt="Sneakers">
                        <span class="type">Sneakers</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item cloathes">
                        <img src="/images/header/Cloathes.svg" alt="Cloathes">
                        <span class="type">Cloathes</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item accessories">
                        <img src="/images/header/Accessories.svg" alt="Accessories">
                        <span class="type">Accessories</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item other">
                        <img src="/images/header/Other.svg" alt="Other">
                        <span class="type">Other</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="bgString">OCTOPU<span class="dark">S</span></div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="mainHeader">
                        <h1>VISUALIZE YOUR ITEM</h1>
                        <button type="button" class="contactBtn">Contact me</button>
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-5"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>

                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="social">
                        <img class="item" src="/images/header/social_behance.svg" alt="Behance">
                        <img class="item" src="/images/header/social_instagram.svg" alt="Instagram">
                        <img class="item" src="/images/header/social_youtube.svg" alt="YouTube">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>



    <!--

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Даже если добавить надписи на фоне свойство display: none, ее отсутствие почти не влияет на этот отступ и он остается в любом случае (скриншот в обновленном вопросе)

Comment: внесла корректировки. Уберите .header .row {height: 85vh} , чтобы дочерние блоки по высоте не распределялись. Кроме того как вариант - каждую строку заворачивать в свой отдельный .row, а не сваливать все в кучу. +И вот вместо кучи пустых блоков... У bootstrap есть классы для отступов offset-lg-1 (ну не возможно же читать код)

Comment: Понял, спасибо за советы и корректировки.